# Registering a Eureka Client to a Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, docker, raspberry-pi, netflix-eureka

i try to connect a Eureka Server to a Eureka Client without success. All in a Container. Docker/Container Network is set to Host.

I tried hosting both on my Desktop: Works
I tried hosting both on my Raspberry pi: Works

But when i host the Server on my Raspberry Pi i can't connect the Service from my Desktop. I tried alot without success.

Sidenote: i can access Eureka Dashboard, and i have another Container running with a successful connection to a SQL database on my Desktop, i guess there shouldn't be a network problem.

Client

```
server:
  port: 9001


spring:
  application.name: USER-SERVICE
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      preferred-networks:
        - 192.168

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    hostname: 192.168.0.20
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defeaultZone: http://192.168.0.69:8761/eureka
```

Server

```
server:
  port: 8761


eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://192.168.0.69:8761/eureka
  instance:
    hostname: 192.168.0.69
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

192.168.0.20 is my desktop
192.168.0.69 is my raspberry pi

Is this even possible? I tried alot different Settings tho... And as i said both hosted local or on the raspberry works.

Thanks in advance

Error Message :

```
2021-08-15 00:40:24.177  INFO 16044 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: You mentioned you are able to solve. Is there anything else you want to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to solve the probelem by adding ${eureka_url:   } to the defaultZone. works perfect now.

```
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${eureka_url:http://192.168.0.69:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    hostname: 192.168.0.69
    prefer-ip-address: true
```